# WordPress get_permalink() inside Ad Inserter block not working

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
  // query db once for permalink
  $permalink = urlencode(get_permalink());
?>

<a href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $permalink; ?>' onclick='javascript:return (function(){window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $permalink; ?>", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=600, scrollbars=yes", false); return false;})();'>
<img onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.8'" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='1'" style="margin-right:5px; width:40px; height:40px" src="data:image/png;base64,..." alt="Facebook Share" />
</a>
```

The above code executes in an Ad Inserter block but returns the wrong permalink.
I have no other plugins installed for debugging purposes so that means no caching enabled.

The code executes w/o error but doesn't return the correct URL.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
get_the_permalink()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/

And I don't think you have to `urlencode()` it.

**Edit**:
It works only in the loop without any parameters. Outside the loop you have to pass the Post ID to the function.

Comment: What's the diff. between get_the_permalink and get_permalink ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: They appear to be the same but correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: `get_the_permalink()` is an alias of `get_permalink()` - I don`t know why but it worked for me a few WP versions ago.